# Delphi helpers scope

Tags: delphi, helper, delphi-xe5

I have a problem with helper re-declaration in Delphi.

**HelperDecl.pas**

```
unit HelperDecl;

interface

type
  TCustomField = Word;

  TCustomFieldHelper = record helper for TCustomField
  public
    procedure SampleMethod();
  end;

implementation

procedure TCustomFieldHelper.SampleMethod();
begin
end;

end.
```

**ScopeTest.pas**

```
unit ScopeTest;

interface

uses HelperDecl;

type
  rec = record
    art: TCustomField;
  end;

implementation

uses System.SysUtils;

procedure DoScopeTest();
var
  a: TCustomField;
  r: rec;
begin
  a := r.art;
  r.art.SampleMethod(); //Here has the compiler no problems
  a.SampleMethod(); //Undeclared identifier 'SampleMethod'
end;

end.
```

But I have defined a helper only for my local data type (yes, it is derived from Word)! The helper in `SysUtils` is the helper for `Word`, not for my custom data type! Hands off my data type!

When I move `uses System.SysUtils;` before `uses HelperDecl;` then it works. But I would like to have an arbitrary units usage order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `TCustomField` and `Word` is the same type and it is not possible to have two record helpers for the same type.

If you instead let `TCustomField` by a *distinct* type, it will work:

```
type
  TCustomField = type Word;
```

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't know about the difference between `= Word` and `= type Word`.

Comment: @Paul: No, it's a bit subtle and maybe not that widely known, but it is documented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi) I actually love record helpers and often declare my own "integers" and "strings" just to be able to add my own methods on them.

Comment: Indeed. But even if I met this in documentation, I would certainly not have paid attention to it without your explicit direction.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi only supports single helper. When you have multiple helpers in scope, helper from nearest scope is used.

> You can define and associate multiple helpers with a single type.
> However, only zero or one helper applies in any specific location in
> source code. The helper defined in the nearest scope will apply. Class
> or record helper scope is determined in the normal Delphi fashion (for
> example, right to left in the unit's uses clause).

[Class and Record Helpers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi))